# QR Encoder titanium module for Android

Tags: titanium-mobile, qr-code, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm looking for a QR generator for Android. I use Titanium and I need a module like this: [qr encoder for iOS](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4657?restoreSearch=true#!overview)

I don't want to depend on thirds or in a website, I want to generate my own QR image for work offline.

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tried these two modules I found on gitTio? Looks like they work both offline.

- http://gitt.io/component/com.acktie.mobile.ios.qr.encoder
- http://gitt.io/component/de.appwerft.qrcode

Comment: The first module is for iOS I'm using it in iOS apps but I need a module for Android. I'll try the second module but I'm looking for a module like the first.